# How to dynamic replace data in var if input value changed

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, I have a very simple code below. I need to change the amount and email every time if someone changes those.

UPDATE:
Thanks to @ellipsis. Your version is almost ideal except send data.
I need to transfer data (html) from function() to document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');

```js
var amount = '';
    var email = '';
    var html='';
      
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#amount").keyup(function() {
        amount = $('#amount').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
          
        var key = '123345';
        var hash = '' //sha256(email+amount+key); // dynamic email & amount

        html = 'src="test.html" '+'amount="' + amount + '" '+'email="' + email + '" '+'hash="' + hash + '" '; 

        $('.check').text('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');

      });

    });
        // I need to add the 'html' below
       document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.html?" method="get">
    <button id="button">Send it</button>
    <input type="text" id="amount" >
    <input type="text" id="email" >
    <p class="check"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Use onChange instead instead of click event for starters.

Comment: what is `var` in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var amount = '';
var email = '';
var html='';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#amount").keyup(function() {
    amount = $('#amount').val();
    email = $('#email').val();
    var key = '123345';
var hash = '' //sha256(email+amount+key); // dynamic email & amount
html = 'src="test.html" '+'amount="' + amount + '" '+'email="' + email + '" '+'hash="' + hash + '" '; 
$('.check').text('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');
//$('.check').html(html);

  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.html?" method="get">
  <button id="button">Send it</button>
  <input type="text" id="amount">
  <input type="text" id="email">

  <p class="check"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at my update. I think the last one what I need to is add 'html' to the document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>'); outside the function to send data outside. Now 'html' is empty becouse I think it takes var html='';

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the `amount` and `email` `vars` in the click. This way you can't access them and just instantiate them in the function scope of the click event.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#amount").click(function(){
    amount = $('#amount').val(); // access the globally declared var amount
    email = $('#email').val(); // access the globally declared var email
  });
});
```

Also using global variables is not a good practice.

**EDIT:**

```
    var amount = '';
    var email = '';
    var html='';
    var key = '123345';
    var hash = '' //sha256(email+amount+key); // dynamic email & amount
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#amount").keyup(function() {
        amount = $('#amount').val();
      });
      $("#email").keyup(function(){
        email = $('#email').val();
      })
      $('#button').click(function(){
       setNewText();
      })
    });

    function setNewText(){
        var html = 'src="test.html" '+'amount="' + amount + '" '+'email="' + email + '" '+'hash="' + hash + '" '; 
        $('.check').text('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');
        document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');

    }
```

You need to have 2 separate events for `email` and `amount` because else you're tracking only one of the input updates. Also I've created another function to easily update the text, to prevent writing the same code twice. You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g7cx1p0h/).

Comment: Thanks, but in your code setNewText() is always activated if someone change amount or email. I need to activate setNewText() if someone presses the button.

Comment: @Dannym do you mean the button with `id="button"`? I've updated my answer.

Comment: basically for now I need to transfer data (html) from function to document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>'); and I think that will be end of the problem. I upated code above

Comment: @Dannym just set `document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');` in the `setNewText` function. I changed my code.

Comment: I've tried do some shortcut $('#button').click(function(){
       document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');
      }) but doesn't work :( No action, no errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your vars all inside the click event function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#amount").click(function(){
        var amount   = $('#amount').val();
        var email     = $('#email').val();
        var key = '123345';
        var hash = sha256(email + amount + key); // dynamic email & amount 

        html = '';
        html += 'tamount="' + amount + '" '; // dynamic 
        html += 'email="' + email + '" '; // dynamic 
        html += 'hash="' + hash + '" '; // dynamic every time

        $('.check').append(html);
        document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" '+html+'>\x3C/script>');
    });
});
```

ADDITION:

Your Problem is that your variables are changing in different scopes.

Your line `$('.check').append(html);` will execute immediately. But in this moment the var `amount` and all other variables are not set, until the user clicked.

Comment: looks fine but now it's active every time when someone changes something in amount. How to replace it every time?

Comment: Sorry, can you please repeat the question with more information?

Comment: Do you have `keyup` instead of `click` as an event? change it back to `click` please.

Comment: Sorry I was out. Have a look at the update. Now works fine except last part

Comment: You mean `$('.check').text(' ...` ?

Comment: To test  the code data is displayed on <p class="check"></p>  but I need to send those data outside. I did update the code above, have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount   = '';
var email     ='';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#amount").change(function(){
    postRun();   
  });
$("#email").change(function(){
    postRun();   
  });
});

function postRun(){

    amount   = $('#amount').val();
    email     = $('#email').val();
    var key     = '123345';
    var hash     = sha256(email+amount+key); // dynamic email & amount 

    html  = '';
    html +='tamount="'+amount+'" '; // dynamic 
    html +='email="'+email+'" '; // dynamic 
    html +='hash="'+hash+'" '; // dynamic every time
}
```